# How do I split a multi-valued p12 certificate into separate certificates

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am attempting to integrate with Apple PNs and I currently have a p12 certificate that has both the Sandbox and Production certs within it. But I have read that Java SSL will only read the first one, and that for JavaPNS (the APN client I am using), says to use separate certs for this reason.

So using something like openssl, how can take my current cert and separate it out into 2 new certs, one for the Sandbox and one for Production.

This has nothing to do with APN, it's just about splitting a p12 cert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you previously mentioned you can use OpenSSL to change the p12 format to a PEM format, the PEM format would be accepted but also not secure with a password so make sure you get what you need.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in yourcertificates.p12 -out certificates.pem -nodes
```

This will put everything in one file, so you will have to open the PEM file in a text editor and take out the required files.

Certificates are separated by

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

Content

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Keys would be separated by

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Content

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Please update your question if you need anymore information.

Comment: But how do I then get those back to p12 files? That is my goal.

Comment: For others, to complete the loop, I used this command once I had the 2 pem files: openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate-dev.pem -inkey certificate-dev.pem -out certificate.dev.ssl.p12 (and the same for the prod file)

Comment: My apologies, I should have included that you are right. 
In future if you have Firefox, you can actually import the bundled.p12 and export the individual p12's out. But that is the lazy mans method ;)